# Gretty static resources realoading problem

Tags: gradle, gretty

I am trying to configure gretty in a way which will allow me to reload static resources like *.html files (which lives inside standard src/webapp/WEB-INF) without server redeploy. However all my attempts were unsuccessful.
I test it by changing html file and reload html page with clear cache inside chrome(ctr+shift+R).

With **Configuration 1**:

```
gretty {
  contextPath = 'john'
  servletContainer = 'jetty9'
  fastReload = true
}
```

Changing of any html page has no effect at all.

With **Configuration 2**:

```
gretty {
  contextPath = 'john'
  servletContainer = 'jetty9'
  fastReload = false
}
```

Changing of any html calls whole server redeploying which I do not want to happen.

Any chance to make this working?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the official [documentation](https://gretty-gradle-plugin.github.io/gretty-doc/Fast-reload.html), Gretty's fast reload handels changes for files and folders located under the `src/main/webapp` directory. For the path `src/webapp/WEB-INF` fast reload is not enabled.

Either you have to move the `webapp` folder to comply with the path requirements or you add the folder to the fast reload feature specifically. The functions `fastReload(String)` 
 and `fastReload(java.io.File)` allow you to specify directories and files for fast reload.

Comment: I've tried and  fastReload = 'src/webapp/WEB-INF' but it cause server reload when I change any resource inside WEB-INF folder

Comment: Are you running your application inplace, using `appRun` or as a war task, via `appRunWar`?

Comment: I run it via gradle task. Gretty -> jettyStart

Comment: I've tried AppRun task. I can see from task output that prepareInplaceWebAppClasses had been called. But changing of resource inside webapp folder does not reflected in web browser :(

Comment: To be able to use fastReload, you have to run your application in inplace mode using ´appRun´. You can't find this in the official documentation but in Gretty's source code.

Comment: Please add your custom webapp folder to Gretty's `extraResourceBase`. You don't need to add your folder to the fastReload feature using `fastReload(java.io.File)` this way. Check here: https://gretty-gradle-plugin.github.io/gretty-doc/Web-app-extra-resource-bases.html

Comment: Sorry, extraResourceBase did not help